# When and where did Hasan ibn Ali(RA) die?

Tags: history, caliph, hussain

When and where did Hazrat Hasan(RA), son of Hazrat Ali and the grandchild of Prophet Muhammad(PBUH) die?

Answer (score 1):

Sunni and Shiite sources almost agree that the killer of Hassan Ibn Ali, Jada, the daughter of Ash'ath bin Qais Kennedy, was the Imam's wife. But the main motivator and indirect cause of the martyrdom of Imam PBUH was Mu'awiyah. According to almost all Shiite and Sunni sources, Mu'awiyah sent 100,000 dirhams to Jada when he tried to pledge allegiance to succeed his son Yazid, promising to poison Hassan Ibn Ali (the second Imam of the Shiites). He marries Yazid. Some have said that Mu'awiyah even sent poison to Jada and cited a bunch of sources as mere financial greed.
According to various narrations, 3 days or 40 days or two months after eating the poison, this grandson of the Prophet passed away.
In various sources, the date of martyrdom of Imam Hassan (as) is stated in the years 49, 50 or 51 AH. Among these, Shiite sources have mainly mentioned the month of Safar and Sunni sources have mentioned the month of Rabi al-Awal as the time of the martyrdom of Imam PBUH.

https://wiki.ahlolbait.com/%D8%B4%D9%87%D8%A7%D8%AF%D8%AA_%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A7%D9%85_%D8%AD%D8%B3%D9%86_%D8%B9%D9%84%DB%8C%D9%87_%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B3%D9%84%D8%A7%D9%85

Comment: Sunni sources do not say that at all! they say that the wife of Hasan (RA) plotted and poisoned Hasan (RA) who had no link whatsoever with Amir Muawiyah (RA).